# Postfix mail queue is empty but emails keep coming?

Tags: postfix, sendmail, email

I have typed in "mailq" in command line and it shows 0 mail in queue, however postfix is sending out emails every 5min. How is this possible? The emails were requested 1 hour ago by me during testing and were never sent, but now they are being sent randomly. Why aren't they shown in queue? I have "softbounce" enabled is this the problem?

Answer (score 2):

go ahead and stop postfix and clear out /var/spool/postfix/active then restart it. Obviously you'll need to verify if any of these messages are legit or not.